# Mathematica Destructuring

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, code-generation

#### Context

I'm writing a function that look something like:

```
triDiagonalQ[mat_] := MapIndexed[ #1 == 0 || Abs[#2[[1]]-#2[[2]]] <= 1 &, mat, {2}] //
     Flatten // And @@ # &
```

Now, things like `#2[[1]]` and `#2[[2]]` are somewhat hard to read. I'd prefer to do something like:

```
triDiagonalQ[mat_] := MapIndexed[ #1 == 0 || Abs[i-j] <= 1 &, mat, {2}] // 
    Flatten // And @@ # & (* with a {i, j} <- #2 somewhere *)
```

#### Question

Is there someway to do something like "destructuring" in *Mathematica*?

---

The following links convey what I mean by "destructuring":

- http://clojure.org/special_forms
- http://java.dzone.com/articles/clojure-destructuring
- http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/07/clojure-destructuring.html

(These have nothing to do with *Mathematica*; they're posted mainly to demonstrate what is meant by "destructuring")

Comment: Power Programming with Mathematica: The Kernel by David B. Wagner has a Chapter 6.1.2 Destructuring. "the technique of extracting parts of patterns using pattern variables is sometimes called *destructuring*".

 (I know I'm late to the party but thought it relevant givin the valuable dicussion resulting from this question).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use macros / code generation to be able to use the syntax you like. Here is one possibility:

```
ClearAll[withLiteralIndices];
SetAttributes[withLiteralIndices, HoldAll];
withLiteralIndices[code_, inds : {__Symbol}] :=
  Block[inds,
     Unevaluated[code] /.
       MapIndexed[
          Function[{i, pos}, pos /. {p_} :> (i :> #2[[p]])], 
          inds
       ]
  ]
```

Now, you can pretty much *literally* use the code you would like to use:

```
withLiteralIndices[
  triDiagonalQ[mat_] := 
     MapIndexed[#1 == 0 || Abs[i - j] <= 1 &, mat, {2}] // Flatten // And @@ # &,
  {i, j}
]
```

When you look at the resulting definition, you can see that this is entirely equivalent to hand-written code using slots:

```
?triDiagonalQ

(*
  Global`triDiagonalQ

  triDiagonalQ[mat_]:=
    (And@@#1&)[Flatten[MapIndexed[#1==0||Abs[#2[[1]]-#2[[2]]]<=1&,mat,{2}]]]
*)
```

**EDIT**

Here is a simpler and perhaps more elegant version of the macro, which uses the  [injector pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1929/injecting-a-sequence-of-expressions-into-a-held-expression/1937#1937) more explicitly:

```
ClearAll[withLiteralIndices];
SetAttributes[withLiteralIndices, HoldAll];
withLiteralIndices[code_, inds : {__Symbol}] :=
  Block[inds,
     Unevaluated[code] /.
        Replace[
          Range[Length[inds]],
          p_ :> (inds[[p]] :> #2[[p]]),
          {1}
        ]
  ]
```

Comment: I don't understand this yet, but I will meditate on it. You should write a "On Mathematica", like the Mathematica version of "On Lisp".

Comment: @term-rewritica I should first read some more elementary Lisp books, like ANSI CL by the same PG, or Seibel's book. It has been several years already that I promise this to myself. Thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 42):

Leonid provides a nice method for doing this within "pure functions" but I think it should be pointed out that the common method for doing this is pattern matching.

**I argue that destructuring is the *foundational use* of pattern matching in *Mathematica*.**

Every replacement pattern, be it an explicit rule (`:>`, `->`) or part of a definition (`:=`, `=`), that uses a named pattern on the left-hand side that does not match the entire expression or argument is doing destructuring.

Applied to your specific example:

```
f[a_, {i_, j_}] := a == 0 || Abs[i - j] <= 1

triDiagonalQ[mat_] := And @@ Flatten @ MapIndexed[f, mat, {2}]
```

Or:

```
triDiagonalQ[mat_] := And @@ Flatten @
   MapIndexed[#2 /. {i_, j_} :> # == 0 || Abs[i - j] <= 1 &, mat, {2}]
```

The second example is almost exactly what you asked for: "with a `{i, j} <- #2` somewhere"
It's just turned around: `#2 /. {i_, j_}`.

This destructuring is common in *Mathematica* programming for experienced users.

Among many examples:

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2450/121) I use it to separate `a + b + c`:

```
(a + b + c) /. head_[body___] :> {head, body}  (* Out= {Plus, a, b, c} *)
```

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5756/121) Leonid uses it in a recursive function. (`{x_, y_List}`)

Szabolcs uses it in [`iter`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1328/121), also recursive.

Heike uses it with `/.` in [`PerforatePolygons`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5891/121) and with `:=` in [`torn`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4155/121).

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7882/121) I used it simply in `formula` but also in `MakeBoxes[defer[args__], fmt_] :=` where the parameter pattern `defer[args__]` serves to match the literal head `defer` while also destructuring.

In [`withOptions`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3259/121) it is used both in the function definition and in the replacement rule.

The ["injector pattern"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1937/121) is a form of destructing.

I also used it in [`inside`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9410/121), [`withTaggedMsg`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8219/121), [`pwSplit`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1129/121), [`dPcore`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7512/121) etc.

---

Another, simpler form of destructuring exists in the form of `Set` and `List` (`{}`).  A matching `List` structure on the left and right sides of `=` will assign values part-wise.

```
{{a, b}, c, {d}} = {{1, 2}, 3, {4}};

{a, b, c, d}
```

> ```
>  {1, 2, 3, 4}
> ```

This is used e.g. in the first [`LUDecomposition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LUDecomposition.html) example, and R.M uses it [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4027/121).

Comment: This is a very cute use of pattern matching. Never thought of it.

Comment: (purely out of courisity) Can pattern matching be combined with anonymous functions (i.e. #1 #2 ... &), or is it only for named functions?

Comment: @term-rewritica it is not just a "cute" use, it is the foundational use.  This *is* destructuring in *Mathematica*.  My second example is a combination of pattern matching and anonymous functions.  The second example is almost exactly what you asked for: "with a `{i, j} <- #2` somewhere" -- it's just turned around (`#2 /. {i_, j_}`).

Comment: you're absolute right, I missed the ingenuinity of the /. {i+, j_} :> in the second example. :-) I'm going to try to work this into my "default/habitual mathematica style"

Answer (score 21):

I think Mr. Wizard provided a very thorough answer to the question. I would however like to add a slight example of wrapping this up nicely in a format similar to `Function[]` but using destructuring:

```
SetAttributes[dFunction, HoldAll]
dFunction[pattern_, body_][arg___] /;MatchQ[{arg}, pattern] := {arg} /. pattern :> body
```

This then allows you to have nice syntax for an anonymous destructuring function using pattern matching:

```
triDiagonalQ3[mat_] := And @@ Flatten@ MapIndexed[
   dFunction[{v_, {i_, j_}}, v == 0 || Abs[i - j] <= 1], mat, {2}]
```

**Syntax**

As to the "clumsiness" of this syntax, I have to agree with Mr. Wizard that it's not as nicely looking as replacement rules, but then again I don't particularly like `Function[x,x^2]` either, and much prefer the aesthetics of the built-in shorthand which looks like `x ↦ x^2`(entered via <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>). The above code can be made to use a similar shorthand rather simply by setting `RightArrowBar = dFunction;` which allows the definition to look like :

```
{v_, {i_, j_}}  ⇥  (v == 0 || Abs[i - j] <= 1)
```

And if one is afraid of using the build-in undefined infix operators, you could of course define a custom symbol for it which doesn't lay claim on `RightArrowBar`. Personally I find this appearance of an anonymous replacement rule based function to be quite nice.

**The value of pattern matching**

As was discussed in comments, one of the interesting behaviors of this construct is that it closely mirrors the behavior of a function defined through pattern matching. if `f[x_Integer]:=...` is defined and called with arguments not matching the pattern the function remains unevaluated. For instance `f[2.3]` will return itself. The same behavior can be observed with `dFunction` where for instance `dFunction[{x_Integer}, x][3.2]` will return itself unevaluated.

Sadly due to the nature of `SubValues`, it's not possible to fully simulate pattern matching functions in an anonymous form using this method, since attributes such as `HoldAll` cannot be implemented. I do belive that this could be implimented using devious hacks similar to the method employed here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5458/1194 by Leonid Shifrin. However I fear that even if I did mange to implement it I would never use the result for fear of unexpected behavior, while I quite like the simplicity of my current `dFunction`.

Comment: I usually like your answers (in fact I know through ♦ magic that I've upvoted your posts more than anyone else), so please don't take offense, but honestly how is that in any way superior to the forms that I show?  It looks very clumsy to me compared to `triDiagonalQ[mat_] := And @@ Flatten @
   MapIndexed[#2 /. {i_, j_} :> # == 0 || Abs[i - j] <= 1 &, mat, {2}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I didn't claim that it was superior in any way. It's a stylistic choice I sometimes find I have a short function which doesn't do much, so I replace it with an anonymous function, however if the function relies on pattern matching, as is often the case for my MapIndexed functions,  I can't easily do this. But with this definition it's no problem. So really it's a style choice. I decided to post it since Mike also commented that it was a shame Function didn't support destructuring.

Comment: +1 Now it would be nice to support attributes

Comment: @Mr.Wizard And another thing, if you call something like `f[_Integer]:=code;f[2.3]` You get the unresolved "call". If you try to emulate this using your method, you get the unchanged input to the replacement, instead of getting the unresolved "call". To be specific `0.3/._Integer:>code` yields `0.3`, while `dFunction[{_Integer},code][0.3]` yields itself, meaning that your output specifies that you have the unresolved call, rather then just passing on the input to higher functions. Speedwice my best bet is that you win by a factor of 2 due to my version having two pattern checks.

Comment: +1 for the `RightArrowBar` thing, which makes this a lot more usable. You're now set up to collect a 100pt bounty.  Congrats!

Comment: I just wanted to say that in the time since I doubted the value of this construct I have come to really see the value in it.  Critical for me is the behavior that the function does not evaluate until the pattern matches.  Please consider placing notice of this behavior conspicuously in your answer.  I'd +1 a second time if I could.

Comment: I just stumbled over this and I have to say I really like it! Using this with the shorthand notation is especially neat!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Subtract` or `Differences` to get the differences in the index and use `FreeQ` to test if every element is `True`. This removes the need for the ugly `#2[[1]]-#2[[2]]` and also the `Flatten` and `And@@` at the end.

```
triDiagonalQ[mat_?MatrixQ] :=FreeQ[MapIndexed[(#1 == 0 || Abs[Subtract @@ #2] <= 1) &, 
      mat, {2}], False]
```

The pattern test `_?MatrixQ` ensures that you only operate on matrices.

Comment: This solution is more elegant than more. However, I'd still like to know how to do destructuring (if possible) :-)

Answer (score 5):

My first answer explains that *Mathematica*'s replacement rules perform destructuring. This answer is intended to complement jVincent's method, which I see is appreciated.

My aim is to provide `Attributes` for the pattern-based function.  This requires that the head evaluate therefore `SubValues` may not be used.  Here are two separate approaches.

### Module

A direct approach is to automate the creation of a new `DownValue` function using `Module`.

```
SetAttributes[pFunc1, HoldAll]

pFunc1[pattern_, body_, attrib_: {}] :=
  Module[{pf},
    SetAttributes[pf, attrib];
    pf[pattern] := body;
    pf
  ]

pFunc1[_[__, b_, c_], Binomial[b, c], HoldAllComplete][9 + 7 + 6 + 3]

pFunc1[PatternSequence[_[__, b_, c_], x_], Binomial[b, c]/x, HoldAllComplete][9 + 7 + 6 + 3, 4]
```

> ```
> 20
>
> 5
> ```

### ReplaceAll

The first method creates a new symbol `pf$xxx` for each use which could be seen as undesirable.  A method that does not is to simply embed a `ReplaceAll` operation in the body of `Function` like this:

```
SetAttributes[pFunc2, HoldAll]

pFunc2[pattern_, body_, attrib_: {}] :=
  Function[
    Null,
    Unevaluated@{##} /. pattern :> body,
    attrib
  ]
```

This method returns an actual `Function` expression rather than a `pf$xxx` symbol.
It also allows mixing `Slot` (`#`) and pattern references in `body` should that be desired.

It however does not return an unevaluated function expression when the arguments do not match the pattern.  (Though one could add a `{__} :> $Failed` type of rule to `/.`, if that is all that is desired.)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you could just use With in a Function?

```
lst = ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}];
MapIndexed[
   Function[{value, pos}, 
      With[{i = pos[[1]], j = pos[[2]]}, 
         {value, i, j}
      ]
   ], 
lst, {2}]
```

Comment: It's a shame that neither With[] nor Function[] support destructuring.