# How to override `?NumericQ`

Tags: function-construction, code-review

I have a function `myFunc` which I is to be displayed cleanly if arguments are symbolic, but which can also be numerically evaluated.  I do this by defining a complicated auxiliary function `pR` which is evaluated only if its arguments are numerical (probably not a good idea?).

```
kin[a_, b_, c_] = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - 2 a b - 2 a c - 2 b c;
pR[s_?NumericQ, m0_?NumericQ, m1_?NumericQ] := 
  1/s*Sqrt[kin[s, m0^2, m1^2]]*Log[(2 m0 m1)/(-s + m0^2 + m1^2 - Sqrt[kin[s, m0^2, m1^2]])]
```

The function (watered-down) I wish to define is

```
myFunc[n_?IntegerQ, s_, m0_, m1_] := 
  Sum[
    Binomial[n + 1, 2 idx3 + 1]*((s + m0^2 - m1^2)/(2 s))^(n - 2 idx3) 
     *(kin[s, m0^2, m1^2]/(4 s^2))^idx3, {idx3, 0, (n + 1)/2}] pR[s, m0, m1];
```

So for example:

```
myFunc[4,s,m,m]//Simplify
(*  ((m^4 - 3 m^2 s + s^2) pR[s, m, m])/s^2   *)
```

and the complicated mess is in `pR`.
The problem I'm running into is:

1. I don't know how to code it so that the user can forcibly display the function `pR` in its entirety -- even if its arguments are symbolic, overriding the `?NumericQ`.
2. I would like to be able to take derivatives (`D`), `Limit`s, and perform a Taylor `Series` expansion on `myFunc` appropriately handling the auxiliary function `pR`.  This should trigger the override in the previous point.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood something, but it's not clear to me why you need `?NumericQ` at all here.  Why did you use it?

Comment: If I didn't have `?NumericQ`, then the output of my example `myFunc[4,s,m,m]` would be drastically more complicated.

Comment: Instead of using NumericQ, you could simply use an inert head in place of `pR`.  If you need the full expression (for numeric evaluation, series expansion, etc.), just `ReplaceAll` that inert head with `pR`: `expr /. someHead -> pR`.

Comment: @Szabolcs You mean as done in the answer below? :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, even simpler than that.  No need for and `expandPR` which contains the definition of `pR`.  I find that unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @Szabolcs Okay, I see the distinction.  Nevertheless that inert head would have to be named (or `Format`ed; potentially confusing) something understandable.  You still need two symbols either way, right?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't think that there's a need for `Format` or anything complicated at all.  Just don't put `pR` in `myFunc`.  Put `inertpR` instead.  Then when you need to have the full expression, just do `... /. inertpR -> pR`.  Usually this can be done either before before or after doing operations like taking derivatives, series expansion or substituting numerical values.  Instead of having an auxiliary function `expandPR`, we have a short one liner (`/. inertpR -> pR`), so it's easy to be flexible about naming that head.  Also, we can use `pR` whenever we want without needing to apply...

Comment: ... `expandPR` *in addition*.  Of course whether to put the function definition into a rule or replace the function *head* instead is a matter of preference and there's no point in writing another full answer for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, you just use an expansion function which applies the pattern without the numeric constraint:

```
expandPR[exp_] := exp /. pR[s_, m0_, m1_] :> 
 1/s*Sqrt[kin[s, m0^2, m1^2]]*Log[(2 m0 m1)/(-s + m0^2 + m1^2 - Sqrt[kin[s, m0^2, m1^2]])]

myFunc[4,s,m,m]//expandPR//Simplify
```

> ```
> ((m^4 - 3 m^2 s + s^2) pR[s, m, m])/s^2
> ```

```
myFunc[4,s,m,m]//expandPR//Simplify
```

> ```
> (Sqrt[s (-4 m^2 + s)] (m^4 - 3 m^2 s + s^2) Log[-((
>  2 m^2)/(-2 m^2 + s + Sqrt[s (-4 m^2 + s)]))])/s^3
> ```

For the second one, you can always expand the definition and find the derivative. If that doesn't work for you, if for instance you want to express the derivative with respect to other `pR` functions, you can always define custom up-values for the derivative operator `D` and try to do some contraction over your function definition or something like that:

```
 pR /: D[pR[s_, m0_, m1_], d_] := D[pR[s, m0, m1] // expandPR, d]

 D[pR[x, k, m], k]
```

> (1/(2 k m x))
>    Sqrt[k^4 - 2 k^2 m^2 + m^4 - 2 k^2 x - 2 m^2 x + 
>      x^2] (k^2 + m^2 - x - Sqrt[
>       k^4 - 2 k^2 m^2 + m^4 - 2 k^2 x - 2 m^2 x + x^2]) (-((
>        2 k m (2 k - (4 k^3 - 4 k m^2 - 4 k x)/(
>           2 Sqrt[k^4 - 2 k^2 m^2 + m^4 - 2 k^2 x - 2 m^2 x + 
>             x^2])))/(k^2 + m^2 - x - Sqrt[
>          k^4 - 2 k^2 m^2 + m^4 - 2 k^2 x - 2 m^2 x + x^2])^2) + (2 m)/(
>       k^2 + m^2 - x - Sqrt[
>        k^4 - 2 k^2 m^2 + m^4 - 2 k^2 x - 2 m^2 x + x^2])) + ((4 k^3 - 
>       4 k m^2 - 4 k x) Log[(2 k m)/(
>      k^2 + m^2 - x - Sqrt[
>       k^4 - 2 k^2 m^2 + m^4 - 2 k^2 x - 2 m^2 x + x^2])])/(
>    2 x Sqrt[k^4 - 2 k^2 m^2 + m^4 - 2 k^2 x - 2 m^2 x + x^2])

Comment: Very interesting.  I've never seen `:>` before.  It looks like RuleDelayed according to the help.  I'm not sure why it must be implemented here.

Comment: @QuantumDot Seeing as replacement rules, including `RuleDelayed`, are arguably the foundation of the *Mathematica* language I think you better get familiar with them!  In addition the tutorials [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8399/121) a perspective on replacement rules, replete with examples, that you may find helpful.