# Circle as a function parameter

Tags: functions

[image]

What I want to do is to find a circle which is tanget to the three big ones. I tried the code below:

```
    findSmallCircle[c1_Circle, c2_Circle, c3_Circle] :=
```

But how do I get the center point and radius of each circle c1, c2, c3, and if this cannot be done, what else can I try?

Excuse me if this is a silly question -- I am new to *Mathematica*

Comment: If it's always 3 circles, you can just write `findCircle[Circle[c1_,r1_],Circle[c2_,r2_],Circle[c3_,r3_]] :=` and use the centers `c1..c3` and radii `r1..r3` in the function body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all your parameter syntax is not correct; you'll want to use `c1_Circle` which is a Pattern named `c1` for an expression with a head `Circle`.  Your `c1_?Circle` is a Pattern named `c1` *that passes the test function* `Circle` (see [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PatternTest.html)), which of course is not valid for the built-in function `Circle`.

---

You removed the issue above from your question.  What remains seems underspecified.  You can extract the centers and radii either with patterns (useful for inserting these parts into a specific expression), or simply using `Apply`, e.g.:

```
f1[cirs__Circle] := {cirs} /.  Circle[center_, radius_] :> {center, radius}

f1[Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Circle[{1, 1}, 3], Circle[{2, 2}, 2]]
```

> ```
> {{{0, 0}, 1}, {{1, 1}, 3}, {{2, 2}, 2}}
> ```

```
f2[cirs__Circle] := List @@@ {cirs}

f2[Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Circle[{1, 1}, 3], Circle[{2, 2}, 2]]
```

> ```
> {{{0, 0}, 1}, {{1, 1}, 3}, {{2, 2}, 2}}
> ```

If you are interested in the actual calculation of the inner circle you will need to describe the characteristics of the function input.

---

Since the element manipulation was indeed your focus let me expand upon what I wrote above with a few additional examples.

The replacement rule `Circle[center_, radius_] :> {center, radius}` is a very simple example of the kind of [destructuring](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8399/121) that is possible with pattern-based transformations.  These can be done either with `RuleDelayed` as above, or as part of a `SetDelayed` definition.  You can also be more specific with the patterns, or provide for different cases to accommodate a flexible syntax.  The documentation for `Circle` shows a number of different acceptable syntax forms, and to be robust your function should be able to handle these to some degree.  As an example I will give a rule that will give a list `{x, y, radius}` for a variety of `Circle` forms.

```
{
  Circle[{1, 2}],
  Circle[{3, 4}, 7.5],
  Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {Pi/6, 3 Pi/4}]
} /. Circle[{x_, y_}, r_: 1, ___] :> {x, y, r}
```

{{1, 2, 1}, {3, 4, 7.5}, {0, 0, 1}}

Note that right-hand-side of `:>` could be any expression into which to substitute values for `x`, `y`, `r`.  Here the pattern `r_:1` represents a pattern with an [`Optional`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Optional.html) value `1` which is used in the case of `Circle[{1, 2}]`.

If you do not require the flexibility and argument testing of pattern matching `Apply` can be used, of which `@@@` is a short form for `Apply` at *levelspec* `1`.  In addition to `List` as used above this can be any head or function.  For example:

```
{#, #2} & @@ Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {Pi/6, 3 Pi/4}]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0}, 1}
> ```

Comment: thanks, so If I dont use `?Circle`, how do I get the data of circle?

Comment: @tintin I added another section to my answer; I don't know if this is what you are after, or the actual calculation of the inner circle.  Please clarify.

Comment: thanks so much for that, I know how to generate the answer if I have the data, my question is to access the circle data,and you do help a lot. thanks for your effort

Comment: @tintin You're welcome.  I extended my answer; I hope you find the addition informative.