# How can I create currying functions using pure function syntax?

Tags: function-construction, syntax, pure-function

For example how can I write

```
In:
pureFunctionSyntax[myF] /@ {7, 3}
Out:
{myF[7, Log[7]], myF[3, Log[3]]}
```

Comment: This may be closely related: [Overlapping pure functions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28983/5478)

Answer (score 11):

Imo the most common/readable/flexible way:

```
Function[h, h[#, Log[#]] &][myF] /@ {7, 3}
```

---

and for fun, less general, as pointed in comments:

```
Through@*#[Identity, Log] &[myF] /@ {7, 3}
```

which can be even shorter, thanks to [ybeltukov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4678/ybeltukov)

```
Through@*#[# &, Log] &[myF] /@ {7, 3}
```

Comment: Wow, you can write even shorter `Through@*#[# &, Log] &`.

Comment: @ybeltukov ah, of course, thanks :)

Comment: This wont work if `myF` has a definition. For example `Through@*#[Identity, Log] &[f[#1] + #2 &] /@ {7, 3}` outputs `{Log[7] + f[Identity][7], Log[3] + f[Identity][3]}` not `{f[7] + Log[7], f[3] + Log[3]}`.

Comment: @user This is one of reasons why I've said it is less general, but the first one will work anyway.

Comment: @user I've edited the question to stress out your concerns.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can use only pure functions:

```
f = ## &[#, Log@#] & /* # &;

f[myF] /@ {7, 3}
(* {myF[7, Log[7]], myF[3, Log[3]]} *)
```

It can be shorter with a bit different syntax:

```
g = ## &[#, Log@#] &;
g /* myF /@ {7, 3}
(* {myF[7, Log[7]], myF[3, Log[3]]} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

I like this syntax:

```
In:
f[#, Log[#]] & /. f -> # &[myF] /@ {7, 3}
Out:
{myF[7, Log[7]], myF[3, Log[3]]}
```