# How can I get a certain kind of iteration?

Tags: list-manipulation

Can I get this type of do-loop in *Mathematica*?

```
Do[Print[j," ",k," ",l], {j,k,l, {a, b,z}, { c, d,y} }]
```

I want this to work so that, in the first iteration, `j`, `k` and `l` take on the values `{a, b, z}` and then, in the second iteration, the values `{c, d, y}`.

So the result should be

> ```
> a b z
> c d y
> ```

I'm interested in any kind of a looping structure which can do this job for me. I don't necessarily need a do-loop.

Comment: As I mentioned at the last I want a loop , as printing is not my goal. I have to evaluate some expression there instead of Printing. Thanks

Comment: @Kuba, Hello I need the second one, that is one loop over sets of three arguments choosing from an array of order n * 3.

Comment: @Kuba,thanks for the help. Now I can do what I wanted.f[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_] := x1 + x2 + x3 + x4;     
f[#1, x2, #2, #3] &[a, b, z] ;  
Do[Print[f[#1, #2, #3, x4] &[i[[1]], i[[2]], 
   i[[3]]]], {i, {{a, b, z}, {c, d, y}}}];.   I have used [i[[1]], i[[2]], 
   i[[3]]]]. Please tell me whether there is any equivalent easy way of writing this. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *Mathematica*, we are far more likely to map functions over lists in various ways than to use looping constructs. Since the functions that are mapped are often very specialized and not for general use, they are -- more often than not -- defined as [pure functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PureFunctions.html).

Here are two non-looping iterators that can do what you ask. They will work on lists of triplets on any length, and the length does not have to be known. The first method preserves some semblance to your formuation of the problem.

```
data = {{a, b, z}, {c, d, y}};
Print[#1, " ", #2, " ", #3] & @@@ data;
```

> ```
> a b z
>
> c d y
> ```

This second method adheres closer to normal *Mathematica*  functional programming style.

```
Row[#, " "] & /@ data // Column
```

> ```
> a b z
> c d y
> ```

In both cases the results are purely for display. Note that first method produces a new cell for each sub-list, while the second always produces a single cell.

Answer (score 1):

While m_goldberg is entirely correct that there are more idiomatic approaches within *Mathematica* I would like to answer the question that was asked.  Yes, you can get that kind of iteration.  You need to be familiar with the different scoping constructs in *Mathematica* to understand one of the choices that you face.  `Do` and `Table` operate by the mechanism of [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) in that they temporarily change the value of their iterators.  So for example:

```
foo := bar

Do[Print[foo], {bar, 1, 3}]    (* outputs 1, 2, 3 *)
```

In many cases, such as your example, you do not need that behavior; it is sufficient to replace literal appearances of the iterator variables in the body of the loop.  This is akin to [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) or [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html).  If so we can use [destructuring](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/mathematica-destructuring/8399#8399) to assign values to the variables:

```
Do[
  iter /. {j_, k_, l_} :> Print[j, " ", k, " ", l],
  {iter, {{a, b, z}, {c, d, y}}}
]
```

If you *do* need the full `Block`-like scoping then you need something more.  I will use `Block` to prevent external modification of the working variables.  Using a different form of destructuring the assignment `{j, k, l} = iter` is made as the first operation in the body of the loop, separated by [`CompoundExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html).

```
foo := Sequence[j, " ", k, " ", l];

Block[{j, k, l},
  Do[
    {j, k, l} = iter; Print[foo],
    {iter, {{a, b, z}, {c, d, y}}}
  ]
]
```