# Is there a way to make the Function construct accept a list as argument?

Tags: function-construction

Is there a way to make the `Function` construct accept a list as argument ?

Writing

```
Function[{x,y},{x+y,x-y}]
```

does not work, since it accepts two arguments and not a single list.

My aim is to generate a table of functions, say

```
Table[Function[{x,y},{x + k y,x - k y}] , {k,1,10}]
```

and then to compose them in different ways. Since every such function returns a list, I would like it also to accept a list, to enable composition.

Comment: `Function[list, {list[[1]] + list[[2]], list[[1]] - list[[2]]}][{a, b}]`

Comment: Also may be useful: [(8382)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8382/121)

Answer (score 3):

The simple way is to write

```
func = Table[With[{k = k}, {#[[1]] + k #[[2]], #[[1]] - k #[[2]]} &], {k, 10}];
```

then

```
Through[func[{a, b}]]
```

gives

> ```
> {{a + b, a - b}, {a + 2 b, a - 2 b}, {a + 3 b, a - 3 b}, {a + 4 b, a - 4 b}, 
>  {a + 5 b, a - 5 b}, {a + 6 b, a - 6 b}, {a + 7 b, a - 7 b}, {a + 8 b, a - 8 b}, 
>  {a + 9 b, a - 9 b}, {a + 10 b, a - 10 b}}
> ```