# What is a good way to specify multiple types of an object?

Tags: syntax

In object-oriented programming paradigm, as far as I know(I'm also an amateur at that :-) ), one often defined some classes, say `Dogs` and `Cats`, and declare some objects as those types, say `Dogs Cody`, `Cats Lucy`. And one may define a function `shout()` with respect to the classes `Dogs` and `Cats` to get the sound when that animal shout. Then he or she may evaluate `Cody.shout()` and get the string `"Growl!"`, while `Lucy.shout()` gets `"Meow~~"`.

Back to Mathematica, I found some article here said that types are corresponding to the `Head` in Mathematica. For example, such things may be implemented as

```
shout[x_Dogs] := "Growl!"
shout[x_Cats] := "Meow~~"
shout[Dogs[Cody]](*Cody is a dog, which is  indicated by its head*)
shout[Cats[Lucy]]
shout[Birds[Lilly]] (*we don't know how it shouts*)
```

and the output is

```
"Growl!"
"Meow~~"
shout[Birds[Lilly]]
```

The first question, is it a good way to implement like this? Is this paradigm proper and wise enough?
The second question, is using a `Head` to indicate what the type of the object is, limited or not flexible? Since an object can have(belongs to) multiple types at the same time. For example, if `x` is a person, then he may have several nationalities(suppose it is legal :)), such as American and Chinese. Then, if we use

```
American[x]
```

To indicate the "type" of this person is `American`, we can't specify that he is also `Chinese`, since using `Chinese[x]` would be two different objects. Hence, I wonder if `Head` is a good way to implement such idea? Or can it be slightly modified and get what we want? Hmm.. I roughly come up with four idea.

**One**:
Using a list as "multiple heads", such like `{Chinese, American}[x]`

**Two:**
To define a concrete "type" function to deal with this things, such as

```
Type[x]={American,Chinese}
```

**Three:**
`Elements[x,American]`(Not sure the right usage of `Elements`. Can user define their own *domain*?)

**Four:**

Use a predicate to indicate these relationship.

```
IsAmerican[x]=True
IsChinese[x]=True
```

---

Which is/are proper or good, or none of?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/object-oriented?sort=votes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made a good observation about how patterns can be used to implement paradigms which are reminiscent of object-oriented programming. You can do a lot of things with patterns, you're not limited to just looking at the head:

```
animals = {Animal["Dog", "Cody"], Animal["Cat", "Lucy"]};
shout[Animal["Dog", _]] := "Growl"
shout[Animal["Cat", _]] := "Meow"

shout /@ animals
```

> `{"Growl", "Meow"}`

You can also get "properties" easily:

```
name[Animal[_, name_]] := name
name /@ animals
```

> `{"Cody", "Lucy"}`

It can be even more general by using conditions:

```
people = {
   Person["Gustav", {"Swedish"}],
   Person["Cody", {"American", "Chinese"}],
   Person["John", {"Swedish", "American"}]
   };

greeting[Person[_, citizenship_]] /; 
  ContainsOnly[citizenship, {"Swedish"}] := "Hej"
greeting[Person[_, citizenship_]] /; 
  ContainsAny[citizenship, {"Chinese", "Vietnamese"}] := "Howdy"
greeting[Person[_, citizenship_]] /; 
  ContainsAll[citizenship, {"Swedish", "American"}] := "Hi"
```

> `{"Hej", "Howdy", "Hi"}`

Comment: Thanks! I see. By the way, I'm not a fan of OOP, actually I'm inexperienced in it. But I'm a fan in MMA paradigm. :) So I ask this question not because I want to mimic something in the OOP paradigm in Mathematica, but because I "guess" when organizing a big project, we inevitably or naturally need such "type"-like abstraction, and I wonder how to do it. So may I further ask that is it common for Mathematica programmers to so? Or do people actually use another abstraction(paradigm)? :)

Comment: @Eric There are some who have attempted to implement object-oriented programming paradigms in Mathematica. But this is not like that, what I describe in this answer uses Mathematica's strengths very well and is a common technique in the Mathematica community. It's related to "destructuring", which you can read more about [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8399/731). I don't think this paradigm in itself has a name, it just is what it is because of how the language is designed.