# Map substitution of variable in expression

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

If I have an expression involving a variable `x`, like `2x+1`, and I have a list of different possible `x` values, like `{1,2,3}`, is there a short way to "map" the expression over the list, returning a new list? This is one way I found:

```
(2x+1) /. x -> # & /@ {1,2,3}
```

But that has a lot of symbols in between the `(2x+1)` and the `{1,2,3}`. Is there a shorter way?

The expression might not necessarily be distributive over a list so `(2x+1) /. x -> {1,2,3}` won't work.

Comment: Does `Function[x, 2 x + 1] /@ {1, 2, 3}` suit your needs? How about `Table[2 x + 1, {x, {1, 2, 3}}]`?

Comment: If you do not like using those `#,/@` symbols, you could always write `ReplaceAll[(2 x + 1), x -> {1, 2, 3}]`

Comment: @J.M. That `Table` method seems much more readable. Thanks.

Comment: Also this would work: (2 x + 1) /. x -> Range[3]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### `Function` shorthand

A *short* way is to use this [`Function`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) notation:

```
(x \[Function] 2 x + 1) /@ {1, 2, 3}      (* output: {3, 5, 7} *)
```

In a Notebook this formats as:

[image]

The `\[Function]` operator can be entered with <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>.

---

#### `Cases`

Nasser's suggestion does not meet your requirements because it relies on [listability](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) just as `(2x+1) /. x -> {1,2,3}` does.  However you can invert the rule like this:

```
Cases[{1, 2, 3}, x_ :> 2 x + 1]           (* output: {3, 5, 7} *)
```

By using [`Rule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) rather than [`RuleDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) you can also use an external definition:

```
foo = 2 x + 1;

Cases[{1, 2, 3}, x_ -> foo]               (* output: {3, 5, 7} *)
```

Recommended reading:

- [Mathematica Destructuring](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8382/121)

---

#### `Table`

Since this answer has been Accepted (thank you) I shall include J. M.'s recommendation of [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) for completeness.

```
Table[2 x + 1, {x, {1, 2, 3}}]            (* output: {3, 5, 7} *)
```

Like `Cases` this can use external definitions if needed:

```
foo = 2 x + 1;
v = {1, 2, 3};
Table[foo, {x, v}]                        (* output: {3, 5, 7} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

To apply each rule separately, we wrap it with `List`

```
2 x + 1 /. {{x -> 1}, {x -> 2}, {x -> 3}}
```

{3, 5, 7}

This translates to

```
2 x + 1 /. List /@ Thread[x -> {1, 2, 3}]
```

{3, 5, 7}

Answer (score 1):

Introducing the attribute `Listable` in your function:

```
Function[x, 2  x + 1, Listable]@{1, 2, 3}

(*{3, 5, 7}*)
```